# How to run Scratch file in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, scratch-file

I am working on a project called "banana" and now I wanna run the Scratch file I already wrote, but I can only find the green triangle which would say "run banana" when you hover over it, but no way to run my scratch file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run your scripts by right-clicking, and clicking run. On Windows, you can also press `ctrl + alt + F10`. (`shift + F10` on Ubuntu, or `Shift + Control + R` on OSX). If that doesn't work, something might be wrong with your python interpreter, make sure it's setup correctly.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F10` is not a good idea on my Ubuntu laptop. A shell opens. Did you mean `Shift`?

Comment: Answer was specifically meant for windows, I edited it... Is the shortcut on ubuntu shift + Alt + f10? I can add that in my answer too.

Comment: It's `Shift + F10`

Comment: For Mac it's `Shift + Control + R`